# Está buscando uma lista do banco de dados e somente no renderItem dá Objeto não definido, alguém me ajude por favor!

Tags: react-native

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { FlatList, SafeAreaView, View, StyleSheet, Image, Text } from "react-native";
import ItemList from './itemList.js';
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite'
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

function openDatabase() {
    if (Platform.OS === "web") {
      return {
        transaction: () => {
          return {
            executeSql: () => {},
          };
        },
      };
    }
    console.log("openDatabase");
    return SQLite.openDatabase("exchange.db");
}

export default function List() {
    const navigation    = useNavigation();

    const db = openDatabase();
    const [header, setHeader] = useState([]);
    db.transaction((tx) => {
        console.log('Entrou no Transaction');
        tx.executeSql(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS header ("
            +"id text PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, "
            +"created_at TEXT, "
            +"updated_at TEXT, "
            +"seal TEXT, "
            +"customer_cod TEXT, "
            +"customer_store TEXT, "
            +"customer_name TEXT, "
            +"city TEXT"
            +");",
            null,
            (txtObj, resultSet) => {
                console.log("success");
            },
            (txtObj, error) => console.log(error)
        );
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(
                'SELECT * FROM header;',
                null,
                (txtObj, resultSet) => setHeader(resultSet.rows._array),
                (txtObj,error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
        });
      }, [header]);
    
      const deleted = (id) => {
        db.transaction(tx => {
          tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM items WHERE id = ? ', [id],
            (txObj, resultSet) => {
              if (resultSet.rowsAffected > 0) {
                let newList = this.state.data.filter(data => {
                  if (data.id === id)
                    return false
                  else
                    return true
                })
                this.setState({ data: newList })
              }
            })
        })
      }
      return(
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList 
                data={header}
                keyExtractor={ header => header.id}
                renderItem={ (header) => <Text >Item: {header.id} </Text>}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={ () => <Separator />}
                />
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}
                onPress={ () => navigation.navigate("Register")}>
                <Image source={ require('../../assets/icons/icons8-add-new-100.png') }/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const Separator = (() => <View style={styles.separator}></View>)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#38a69d'
    },
    separator: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#DDD'
    }
})
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Olá, o problema parece estar na passagem do item de lista para o componente. Experimente colocar na linha do renderItem assim:

```
renderItem={ ({item: header}) => <Text >Item: {header.id} </Text>}
```

Comment: Na mosca manooooo! valeu muito.

Comment: Ainda bem, marque a resposta como correta, por favor. :)